# What does it mean by binary operation ( taking gcd and lcm )?

Tags: boolean-algebra

I'm less than a rookie so it might seem like an easy question but I want a head start to figure things later on my own.
The question wants me to prove that the set $D(m) = \{ x \in \mathbb N - \{0\} : x\mid m \}$ where $m$ is a positive number, is a lattice under two binary operations of taking : gcd and lcm.
So I figured out that first I have to prove that it's a partially ordered set ( reflexive - anti Symmetric - transitive), but the problem here I can't understand what does it mean by these two operations. I need an example on the reflexive part so I could understand. or at least any example. and Sorry for this low Question.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: What are you asking?  What is the meaning of $\gcd$ and $\operatorname{lcm}$????  $\gcd$ is the greatest common divisor (ex.  $\gcd(20,12)=4$ because $4|20$ and $4|12$) and $\operatorname{lcm}$ is least common multiple (ex. $\operatorname{lcm}(20,12)=60$ because $20|60$ and $12|60$.   If you meant some other question could you clarify what you are asking?

Comment: I dont understand how to usethem in the proof, and no I'm not asking what is the meaning of gcd and lcm.

Answer (score 2):

It is reflexive because each number divides itself, so $a$ divides $a$ for every non-zero $a$, it is antisymmetric, because if $a$ divides $b$ and $b$ divides $a$, then $a=\pm b$, but $a$ and $b$ being positive, it must be that $a=b$. Surely you can prove that if $a$ divides $b$ and $b$ divides $c$ then $a$ divides $c$, which is transitivity.

To show that it is a lattice you have to prove that for every two numbers $a$ and $b$ there exist $\inf\{a,b\}$ and $\sup\{a,b\}$. Recall that $\inf\{a,b\}$ must divide both $a$ and $b$ and if $c$ divides both $a$ and $b$, then $c$ must divide  $\inf\{a,b\}$. Dually, both $a$ and $b$ divide $\sup\{a,b\}$ and if both $a$ and $b$ divide $c$, then $\sup\{a,b\}$ must divide $c$. Hence you are left to prove that $\gcd(a,b)$ and $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)$ play the role of $\inf\{a,b\}$ and $\sup\{a,b\}$respectively.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that most of the people are missing PO's question, which is how to use $\operatorname{lcm}$ and $\gcd$.

You need to prove that any subset $\left\{a,b\right\}\subseteq D(m)$ has a least upper bound $\operatorname{LUB}(\left\{a,b\right\})$ and a greatest lower bound $\operatorname{GLB}(\left\{a,b\right\})$ defined by you.

By defining $\operatorname{LUB}(\left\{a,b\right\}) = \operatorname{lcm}(a,b)$ and $\operatorname{GLB}(\left\{a,b\right\})=\gcd(a,b)$, you need to prove that for any $\left\{a,b\right\}\subseteq D(m)$, the $\operatorname{LUB}(\left\{a,b\right\})\in D(m)$ and $\operatorname{GLB}(\left\{a,b\right\})\in D(m)$.

This is easy to prove as if $\left\{a,b\right\}\subseteq D(m)$, then $a\mid m$ and $b\mid m$, hence $\gcd(a,b)\mid m$, so $\operatorname{GLB}(\left\{a,b\right\})\in D(m)$. You can work on the second part. Hint: The expression $ab=\gcd(a,b)\times \operatorname{lcm}(a,b)$ might be useful. Try to think what happens if $\operatorname{LUB}(\left\{a,b\right\})\not\in D(m)$.

Comment: Just be careful. In your problem you are using the poset $D(m)$ with $\text{lcm}$ and $\gcd$. But not all the posets with these two operations will give you a lattice. Example $S=\left\{2,3,6,12,24,36\right\}$, as $\gcd(2,3)$ and $\text{lcm}(24,36)$ are not in $S$.